# Paper trail display has many objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I'm using the paper trail gem to track version changes on order web application. I'm having trouble displaying the has_many versions

Order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :order, order: "position", autosave: true
end
```

line item model:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :line_items
  has_paper_trail
end
```

Order Controller:

```
@order = Order.find(params[:id])
@versions = PaperTrail::Version.where(item_id: params[:id]).order('created_at ASC')
@line_items = LineItem.find_all_by_order_id(params[:id])
@line_item_versions = @line_items.versions
```

history html:

```
<% @line_item_versions.each_with_index do |version, index| %>
  <b>Version: </b><%= index + 1 %><br/>
  Event ID: <%= version.id %><br/>
  <b>Target:</b> <%= version.item_type %>
  <small>(id: <%= version.item_id %>)</small>; <b>action</b> <%= version.event %>;<br/>
<% end %>
```

The problem is the `.versions` works when a single object (from `.find`) is found. However, when an array of objects (from the `.find_all_by`) is passed to the `.versions` it returns this error

```
undefined method `versions' for #<Array:0x007f859d37eb30>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining:

```
@line_items = LineItem.find_all_by_order_id(params[:id])
```

Which means `@line_items` is an Array of several LineItem records. Then, you call:

```
@line_item_versions = @line_items.versions
```

But the `.versions` method is an instance method of LineItem (one `line_item has_many versions`). This causes the error `undefined method 'versions' for Array` (`@line_items` is an array here).

---

**To solve this problem,**
I think you should do the following (but there is many options, depending on what you want to do):

```
<% @line_items.each do |line_item| %>
  <%= line_item.name %>

  <% line_item.versions.each_with_index do |version, index| %>
    <b>Version: </b><%= index + 1 %><br/>
    Event ID: <%= version.id %><br/>
    <b>Target:</b> <%= version.item_type %>
    <small>(id: <%= version.item_id %>)</small>; <b>action</b> <%= version.event %>;<br/>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I just "fixed" it 3 minutes doing just this. Thanks a ton for the help.

Comment: I just found that this solution slightly defeats the problem. If I delete a line_item, then call .versions on all found line_items, it obviously won't show the deleted Line_item.